# Copy element with management function

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, utf-8, python-unicode

I to try run this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        from blogs.models import Blog, Post
        from sitename.settings import DEFAULT_CHARSET

        for blog in Blog.objects.all().using('old'):
            try:
                Blog.objects.get(old_id=blog.id)
                continue
            except:
                pass
            new_blog = Blog(
                name =      blog.name,
                description=blog.description,
                old_id =   blog.id
            )
            new_blog.save()
```

But i have exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I googled this problem and find this solution:

```
name = blog.name.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

The result was upset: All Russian symbols have been removed.

```
"Пост номер 15-14" => "15-14"
```

How shall I copy the data correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you have an issue with charsets of one or both the databases, you should check what encoding you get from the old database and what is in the new one.

your loop looks strange, Django has a nice function `get_or_create` method on `QuerySet`, so there is nice version:

```
for blog in Blog.objects.all().using('old'):
    Blog.objects.get_or_create(old_id=blog.id, defaults={'name': blog.name,
                                                         'description': blog.description})
```